# Discord.Py Cogs проблемы с командой help

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

В файле бота прописано `help_command = None`
Код команды бота:

```py
@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
    print("Наконец-то заработало!")
```

Но взамен выдает ошибку:

> Ignoring exception in command None:
> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "help" is not found

Answer (score 0):

[Решено]

эта строчка не нужна:

```
help_command = None
```

Вместо этого:

```
client.remove_command("help")
```